# Using regexes to modify the text of html (with javascript)

Tags: javascript, android, regex, webview

I want to modify the text in a html file using javascript in an android webview.

Essentially, I want to do what android Linkify does to text, but I don't want to do it with java code, because I feel like that might delay the webview rendering the html (if I parse the text before sending it to the webview).

So, for example a piece of html like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">google.com</a> <!--these two shouldn't be linked-->
    <a href="mailto:akhilcherian@gmail.com">akhilcherian@gmail.com</a> <!--these two shouldn't be linked-->
    <p>www.google.com</p> <!--this should be linked-->
    <p>102-232-2312 2032-122-332 </p><!-- should be linked as numbers-->
</body>
</html>
```

Should become this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">google.com</a>
    <a href="mailto:akhilcherian@gmail.com">akhilcherian@gmail.com</a>
    <p><a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a></p>
    <p><a href="tel:102-232-2312">102-232-2312</a> <a href="tel:2032-122-332>2032-122-332</a> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I **already have the regexes** to convert numbers and email ids to links, and they're working well enough. **What I want to ensure is that I don't link anything that's already within tags**. I've removed anchor tags, so they're not an issue, but I also need to avoid linking things like this:

```
<div width="1000"> <!-- Don't want this '1000' to be linked (but I do want other 4 digit numbers to be)-->
```

So for example if my regex for links is:

```
var replacePattern1 = /((https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim
```

How do I make sure that it's not within < and >? (Answers using javascript would be appreciated, but if you feel like this is a stupid way of doing it, please let me know about alternatives).

If you're answering with javascript, this question can essentially be shortened to:

How do I write a regex in javascript to search for patterns which are not surrounded by '<' '>' tags

Comment: This is a job for a parser, really. Complex html matching is not for regex. Building a regex that made links out of proper formatted links while simultaneously ignoring links that are already links or within attributes of links is a house built of straw: good enough til a good gust comes along. If you must, I'd un-link links that use a protocol at the beginning of the link text (`<a href="http://...">http://...</a> and then re-add them while using a negative lookahead to make sure the link wasn't followed by a ", ', but that still doesn't catch everything. **This is why we have parsers.**

Comment: I've removed all <a> tags and all their inner html. I'm not using regexes to pass the html, but just the text within the html. All I want to do is make sure my regex doesn't apply to something within < > brackets like < 1000 > shouldn't get picked up by a number regex. This should be an easy look around, right?

Can you explain how you would use a parser on an android app with a webview?

Answer (score 0):

So if you use JS than mean is client side, your DOM page have free access of all objects of your page coef events.

May be in this step you dont need to use a regex just using  DOM.

jquery lib can easy update DOM object.

in your step you want only

tag.

So i suggest :

```js
//using jquery
$("p").each(function(){
  console.log($(this))
});

//js 
var paras = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for(p in paras){
  console.log(paras[p]) 
}
```

Comment: This will get me all the p tags, but I want to link all the text in a html file (everything except what's enclosed in '<' '>'. For example if a table row has an email id, I want to link it. It won't be in a <p> tag, and I can't go listing all the tags I want to look at. Besides, a <p> tag might have an <a> tag within, so that doesn't help.

Comment: all the text in a html so i suggest : document.getElementsByTagName("*"); to check all tag html.

Answer (score 0):

As i tell you the deal is manipulate the DOM so example with you step dunno if exactly what you try to get :

```js
var paras = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var hrefs = [];
//what you want to replace in the loop of p
var json_urls = {"links":["http://", "tel:"]};


for(p in paras){
  //copy of text content of your p
  var text_cp = paras[p].textContent;
 //delete the p[i] content
  paras[p].textContent = "";
  //create element dom a
  hrefs[p] = document.createElement("a");
  //i add attribute id with some affectation unique
  hrefs[p].id = "_" + p;
  //add attribute href to a with some affectation replace + content
  hrefs[p].href = json_urls.links[p] + text_cp;
  hrefs[p].textContent = text_cp;
  paras[p].appendChild(hrefs[p]);
}
```